# Can't edit files in Eclipse even though not read-only

Tags: java, eclipse, read-only, ide, write-protect

This is such an amateur question I'm embarrassed I even have to ask.

In Eclipse, sometimes I can't edit a file. I can open it, but it behaves as it if it's a read-only file—typing has no effect. It only happens *sometimes* though, and that's what's driving me crazy.

The only perspectives I use are Java and Perforce, and normally I check out a file via Perforce, like so:

[image: Checking out a file via Perforce]

Once checked out, it looks like this:

[image: A file checked out via Perforce]

But I can't edit this file. Meanwhile, you see the file directly underneath, "VWAPParameterManagerImpl.java"? I can edit *that* one just fine, checking it out using the same steps. Furthermore I was able to edit "VWAP.java" just yesterday@ I have also witnessed this happening with non-java files. In Windows Explorer, I checked the file's attributes and verifed it wasn't read-only (if that means anything; I didn't know what else to check).

**So, why can't I edit files in Eclipse sometimes, and what can I do make such files writable?**

Obviously I can open the file up in `gvim` or another program, but I'd like to edit within Eclipse. I'm primarily a C++ developer and accustomed to a UNIX environment, so this Java/Windows thing is really tripping me up. Thanks in advance to anyone who might be able to advise...

Comment: Permissions issue? Eclipse might be running as a user which has read-only access to the location of your files? Or are the files you can edit in the same directory as ones you can't?

Comment: @J20 - Same directory; that's what's weird.

Comment: Does it behave after you restart Eclipse or close and reopen your editor windows? I have experienced similar in the past on Mac and using IBM RAD (based on Eclipse) under Windows but i always chalked it up to memory/heap issues since it would be fine after a restart.

Answer (score 1):

This is file permissions issue. Perforce is somehow messing with that.

Unlock the file from File Properties and then give Write permissions to yourself.

[image]